# Keep getting Pre-launch report error "Results not available. The devices could not be tested at this time."

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play-console

Some time ago, I got the error `Results not available. The devices could not be tested at this time.` at the Pre-launch report on the Google Play Console. However, it was a completely temporary experience and it was far from the standard result.

This time it's already 2 weeks, with 6 uploaded APKs that I get this error. 6 APKs in a row.

At the beginning, I though it was due to a change I made in the `AndroidManifest.xml` , but I have reverted the change and the error is still there with a new APK. The change in the manifest was an addition of deep links for the main activity:

This is my main activity:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is what I changed:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.SplashScreenActivity"
    android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="my_app_scheme" android:host="deeplink"/>
        <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.mywebsite.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

As I say, I've removed the code, and reuploaded the APK but I keep getting that annoying error. I think that Google Play Console doesn't work well with this configuration (deep links), even though I don't have any troubles with it in any of the devices with what I've tested this `AndroidManifest`. And yes, I added a couple of deep links in the Settings tab of the Pre-launch report. And these deep links work well when I test them on Android Studio. And they are URLs of an alive website.

Does anybody know how to get a bit more of information on why it doesn't work well? I've written an email to the support of Google Play Console, but I don't have much hope that they will come back with a helpful reply.

The test results, for each of the 8 devices is:

> Results not available. The devices could not be tested at this time.

**UPDATE July 2019**

I'm still getting the errors. It's been months since I started getting this issue with absolutely no message being displayed other than the `Results not available. The devices could not be tested at this time.` message.

And to make things worse, I get the Firebase Analytics data polluted due to the Pre-Launch Reports that seem to get launched even after I have deactivated the Pre Launch tests.

**UPDATE 31st August 2019**

Finally, a few days ago, I received a message from the Google Play support team. They have fixed the problem and now it's working completely fine. After dozens of failed APKs/App bundles.

Thanks to @nick-fortescue who I believe helped me to escalate this issue to the correct people.

Comment: The Android app I work on has also started to see a similar issue where the pre-launch report shows `Results not available. The devices could not be tested at this time.`. We've found that the failure of the pre-launch report correlates with releases using app bundles. I assume this is not the issue you're having as you mention many times that you uploaded an APK not an AAB.

Comment: I got excited when you mentioned me @dr_sulli but I've just checked that the dates don't match with your case. For me, it started failing around February. However, I had migrated to app bundles on mid November 2018. There were about 25 app bundles that worked completely alright with the pre-launch reports. It's quite sad, but not my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have talked to some engineers on the pre-launch report and they think it unlikely that your deeplink intent filter is anything relevant, but it is hard for them to check without knowing the app with the problem.

If you want to keep your app package name private, then please report it via the Help menu in the Google Play console (it's behind the question mark icon) and say to the help person you've been asked to send it to the pre-launch report team. You can mention my name if you want. This is probaly the best option as then replies can go to you.

If you are fine adding your app package name on stack overflow, then feel free to add your app name to the question or as a comment here.

Comment: Hi Nick, and thanks for getting involved in this matter :) I don't have any problems with making public the package name, since the app is public itself. It's com.walkaholic.hikeapp

I'm quite sure the intent filter has nothing to do, but since it started failing after I included it, and it happened to me a few months ago, when I tested it as well, I thought there was a connection. Since I've removed it, and it keeps failing, now I believe it's been a coincidence.

Comment: Thanks! I've sent the name over. The relevant engineers aren't in my timezone, so there probably won't be any followup until tomorrow. It's probably still worth you opening a help case using Google Play Console help as then the issue will get tracked and not forgotten.

Comment: I did that yesterday as well. I thought it could take long, and just in case anyone was facing the same issue wrote here too. I'll post the resolution here, hopefully :) Thank you again!

Comment: I have the same problem in that no test was performed on the 13 apk's sent after 05/13/2019. Any solution to our problem?